# How to blur the background when the pop up is opened?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, sass

when i click on any card it shows the pop it's working but i need  my background some blur ,i am trying with some active property and using toggle(); it reflects only on first card i need my background should be blur and onclick of popup close button it should be hidden and displayed only cards with normal[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bq5r.png).How i need means when the popup opens means the background should be blur and pop-up should be highlighted and onclick of close button the popup should be hidden and displays the cards in normal,please help me to fix this

```
<template>
<div class="carddisplay-section">
    <div  v-for="note in notes" :key="note.data" id="blur" class="container note">
        <div @click="toggle()" class="card-content">
            <h5>{{note.title}}</h5>
            <p>{{note.body}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="import-icons">
            <icons class="imported-icons note-icons" />
            <button v-if="flag" class="card-button" type="button" @click="handlesubmit();Togglebtn();">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="popup">
        <UpdateNotes/>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import service from '../service/User'
import icons from './icons'
import UpdateNotes from './UpdateNotes.vue'
export default {
    name: 'DisplayNotes',
    components: {
        icons,UpdateNotes
    },
    data() {
        return {
            flag: true,
            notes: [{
                id: 1,
                title: 'Fundoo',
                body: 'unlimited notes..'
            }, ],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        Togglebtn() {
            this.flag = !this.flag;
        },
        async handlesubmit() {
            service.userDisplayNotes().then(response => {
                this.notes.push(...response.data);
            })
        },
        toggle(){
            var blur=document.getElementById('blur');
            blur.classList.toggle('active');

            var popup=document.getElementById('popup');
            popup.classList.toggle('active');
        }
      
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "@/styles/DisplayNotes.scss";
</style>
```

[DisplayNotes.scss]

```
.carddisplay-section{
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: space-around;
    gap: 10px;
}
.container {
    height: 180px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #e0dede;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 18%;
    margin-right: -15%;
    float: left;
    width: 22%;
}
.card-content {
    h3 {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        padding: 0px 10px;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 17px;
        width: 90%;
        height: 60px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        // padding: 0px 10px;
        outline: none;
    }
}
.card-button {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -19px;
    margin-left: 240px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.note-icons {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.note {
    &:hover {
        .note-icons {
            visibility: visible;
        }
    }
}
.imported-icons {
    margin-top: 17%;
}
#blur.active{
    filter:blur(0.5px);
    // pointer-events: none;
    // user-select: none;
}
#popup{
    position: fixed;
    top:40%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
#popup.active{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new element inside of `carddisplay-section` but outside of `container note` to have the blur. See the comments below.

```
<div class="carddisplay-section" >
  <div id="blur"> <!-- put the id='blur' on this new element -->
    <div  v-for="note in notes" :key="note.data" class="container note">          
      <div @click="toggle()" class="card-content">
        <h5>{{note.title}}</h5>
        <p>{{note.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="import-icons">
        <icons class="imported-icons note-icons" />
        <button v-if="flag" class="card-button" type="button" @click="handlesubmit();Togglebtn();">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- dont' forget the closing tag is before the popup -->
<div id="popup">
    <UpdateNotes/>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @Kinglish ,if i put id in carddisplay-secton ,the pop will open and automatically closed it's mishbehaving, and the background blur will be applied

Comment: I updated my answer. Give it a try. Thanks

Comment: i tried with that @Kinglish, it's not working my card will be shrinking and it overlaps on my side menu bar